# How to overflow the stack without pushing new stack frames?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

One obvious way to cause a stack overflow and get `Segmentation fault` would be to recursively push stack frames on top of each other until it booms. I'm wondering if stack overflow could happen without even pushing new stack frames.

Creating a large enough array could do it too from experience, but any other possible scenarios?

Comment: This would be in Linux/UNIX environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99 uses a resizable array, which you could use and keep resizing it to a larger one. However this resizable array is implemented using `alloca`. Here's a sample code in **UNIX env**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int
main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        void *p = alloca(32UL);
        printf("new memory allocated at %p \n", p);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And your output will look like this

```
new memory allocated at 0xbf800a60 
new memory allocated at 0xbf800a30 
new memory allocated at 0xbf800a00 
new memory allocated at 0xbf8009d0 
new memory allocated at 0xbf8009a0 
[1]    3977 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

`alloca` is in the `malloc` family of functions, except that it allocated memory on the stack by adjusting the stack pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Abuse `alloca()` or `_alloca()` if you're developing on Windows SDK/VS:

> The alloca() function allocates size bytes of space in the stack frame of the
>   caller.

Note `_alloca()` is now deprecated in favour of `_malloca()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally speaking the "stack" is just some memory, and a stack overflow is when ESP / EBP go out of bounds of this memory.

You can accomplish this in a number of ways:

1. Create a huge stack-allocated array that's bigger than the size of the remaining stack space: `int x[10000000];`
2. Set ESP directly: `__asm mov esp, 0x0`
3. Corrupt the stack so when the current function unwinds, ESP/EBP will be set to garbage: `int x; memset(&x, 0, 10000000);`

And countless other ways...

Answer (score 1):

By declaring and using a array larger than your stack size:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
$
```

then

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile char bla[8192 * 1024 + 16] = {0};
}
```

is likely to segfault when executed.

Comment: in my example to avoid the compiler to optimize it out as it is not used elsewhere in the program. If you make a `for` loop to print all elements using `printf` you won't need the `volatile` qualifer as the compiler could not optimize it out.